# Trying to delete rows with cells that have same value as previous in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying remove duplicate records using the A column, and I seem to have *some* success, but I have still found duplicates. Hoping someone will tell me what I can do to improve this.

Thanks

```
Dim i       As Integer
Dim value   As String

i = 3
Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Range("A" & i).Select
    value = ActiveCell.value
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.value = value Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Do you want only the consecutive duplicates to be removed from column A?

Comment: FYI - It's best practice to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following will work for you if you are removing the duplicates for all of column A and it does not have a header row:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: It looks like the asker is only looking to delete consecutive duplicate values.

Comment: His code is to remove only consecutive dupes i guess.

Comment: Because the OP wants the whole row removed, change `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")` to `ActiveSheet.Range("3:10408576")`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know there was already a method that did what I needed (still new to VBA). As I read more on it I saw that there was a value for columns ; Columns:=Array(1,2) I understand that the 2 looks for duplicates in the first 2 columns but what is the 1 for?

Comment: @Jaymes in the array, each column is represented on its on; `Array(2,3)` would look in the second and third columns for the duplicates.  So `Array(1,2,5)` looks in the first, second and fifth column.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using select and active cell.

Use a For loop that loops backwards.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'This can be changed to a specific sheet: Worksheets("sheetName")

With ws

    For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).value Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

This will only compare the value to the one above.  If you want to remove all duplicates use @Petay87 answer.

Comment: suggestion - when doing this set the rows you want to delete to a Range variable then delete the Range at the end. Much faster when doing this on larger data sets

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a row, you need to loop through in reverse. Try the below code,

```
Sub removeDupes() 
Dim i As Long 
For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then 
        Range("A" & i + 1).ClearContents 
    End If 
Next i 
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1 
    If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then 
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete 
    End If 
Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why two steps?  There is no reason to just delete.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just for the OP to understand the functionality better